# Logout y volver atrás en el navegador me muestra zona privada

Tags: laravel

Tras cerrar sesión en laravel 5.4 y usar la flecha de volver atrás del navegador se pueden apreciar las vistas por las cuales estuvo el cliente, si bien no se puede realizar una acción por que la sesion ha finalizado se puede ver toda la información que había en dicha pagina.

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $this->guard()->logout();
    $request->session()->invalidate();
    $request->session()->flush();
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Una solución que encontré para solventar el problema y la dejo con fines demostrativos para que se entienda mejor el problema es la siguiente, pero no es para nada la más optima ya que te carga la pagina por una fracción de segundo y si repites la acción muy rápido el problema sigue.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(history.forward(1)){
        location.replace( history.forward(1) );
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Creo que para eso tienes que usar los middleware auth y guest en los controladores de las vistas que están restringidas, busca información sobre eso

Comment: Estoy usando el middleware de auth, además de uno propio para validar el tipo de usuario. Por otro lado en los controladores volví a comprobar si el usuario estaba logueado if(!\Auth::guest()){}else{abort(503)} para ver si funcionaba, pero no. Leí la documentación y salia que se podía limpiar el request con flush pero tampoco funciona, igual intenté regenerar la sessión y nada.
Intente borrar el caché del sitio desde los meta y tampoco, si bien no se pueden realizar acciones ya que al hacer un click laravel dice que la session expiró te muestra todos los datos cargados previamente

Comment: Wow, es demasiado extraño, nunca me ha pasado algo similar :c

Comment: Encontré una solución temporal y un poco mala, la dejé publicada por si alguien conoce una forma más optima de solventar el problema mediante laravel y no javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo solucione de la siguiente manera:

Cree un middleware con el siguiente código y se lo aplique a las rutas correspondientes.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
  header('Last-Modified:'.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').'GMT');
  header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
  header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0',false);
  header('Pragma: no-cache');
  return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Pero si pones el response en cache esto no se veria afectado al usar no-cache? En mi caso particular

Comment: No sabría decirte, simplemente fue la mejor manera que encontré para solucionar el problema.

Comment: OKOK de todas formas resolvio mi problema igual. jajja

Comment: @CésarAlejandroM Realice lo que mencionas pero sigue sin funcionar, por ejemplo coloque el middleware en la ruta de login y sigue igual.

Comment: @Juanzu Debes aplicar el middleware en todas las rutas que quieres prevenir el volver atrás. Lo que hacen los headers es expirar el caché cuando se sirve la petición

Answer (score 0):

Este problema va un poco mas alla (creo).

Primero debemos retomarnos al navegador y cual es la función de "*atras*". Esta funcion lo que hace es evidentemente mandarnos a la pagina anterior.

Pero si hemos cerrado sesión porque nos muestra contenido privado? R\ No se, aún no lo soluciono. Pero puede ser por ahi la respuesta. Pero esto si es importante, **este contenido no lo busca mediante alguna petición *http* porque evidentemente si lo hace el middleware se activará y lo sacará.**

Al punto. Si tus validaciones de las autenticaciones funcionan de manera correcta, no importa si se carga contenido privado. Estos solo se puede comprobar de las siguientes formas:

1. Recargar la pagina cuando eches hacia "*atras*"
2. Si hay algun formulario, llenalo y envialo.

En todos estos casos si se debe activar el middleware, ya que si se hace una petición **http**. El problema seria que al hacer esto se siga viendo contenido privado.

Espero al menos guiarte a llegar a una solución *temporal* ya que pienso que el problema es del navegador, no de la aplicación.